# Android Table row, cannot center text

Tags: android, android-layout

i have following layout code:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- APP NAME -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2d9adf"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Problem is, that result is not centered (see image below):

[image]

How can I solve it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy fix to this. You need to change your `RelativeLayout` to have the correct dimensions:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

That way it will stretch the full size of the `TableRow` at the top. Then you can add this to your `TextView`:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

to center the `TextView` in the `RelativeLayout`, which is spanning the `TableRow`.